# What is a VN01A Transistor?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, components

I was looking at the schematic on page 10 of this application note: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva557/snva557.pdf

I was looking to order parts for it but I am having trouble finding parts for Q1 and Q2. The schematic symbol is for a N-Channel Depletion Mode Single Gate MOSFET and they are labled as VN01A. I tried searching for this component, but nothing came up.

Does VN01A refer to a family of MOSFETs or is it an obsolete part? Can anyone recommend a component that works with this schematic?

Comment: NDMOSFETs are **incredibly** hard to find as of late. Even PDMOSFETs are rare.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Am I right in thinking that ND and PD MOSFETS are part of the LDMOSFET family?

Comment: @Polynomial: No, "LD" stands for "Laterally-Diffused" whereas the "D" stands for "Depletion-mode". They are different things.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Cool. Wasn't sure, as I'd come across LDMOSFET but not the PD or ND prefixes before.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- actually, I know of several NDMOSFET parts but *no* PDMOSFETs *whatsoever*

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Maybe that's what I was thinking then. Mouser shows 108 NDMOSFETs and 2 PDMOSFETs.

Comment: Since the transistors are used in an op amp feedback loop you can probably substitute a current-mode DAC for even finer control of the charge rate.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: And when I look at the datasheets for the "PDMOSFETs" they're actually enhancement mode >.>

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- it sounds like we all need to use the REport Error button on Mouser more...>.>

Answer (score 3):

First off -- the schematic is using the wrong symbol.  The VN01A appears to be an *enhancement* mode part from its role in the circuit and the part number -- all Supertex depletion mode parts have a D in their part number such as LND01 or DN3765.  (Microchip still makes them, BTW.)

As to the part number itself, the VN01A is an older Supertex N-channel part that appears to be obsolete.  Given the noncritical small-signal switching application the circuit from the linked application note uses them in, and the note about the schematic symbol listed above, I'd substitute any jellybean N-channel FET in TO-92 or SOT-23.

Comment: Those FETs are only used to switch R2 and R11 in and out of the circuit when needed. As the answer states many devices would suit - BSS138 is one of my favourites.

Comment: Ok, so the transistors are just working as on/off switches to control the type of current protection being used, meaning that the component choice is non-critical. That makes sense.

Comment: Also because of their odd choice to use NDMOSFETs that means that when the logic levels are low, both resistors with be in the circuit, which would then lead to the lowest trickle current level. Is that correct?

Comment: @EmmettP -- they used the wrong schematic symbol :P the part they spec'ed is likely an enhancement mode part after all.

Comment: I am planning to use this circuit with Ni-Mh batteries, which need the lowest level of trickle charge, so I could just leave the transistors out entirely and have both resistors always in the circuit.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Okay, so these resistors being in circuit actually increases the current going to the battery. So to have a trickle charge current of c/40 when the overcharge protection is activated, which is my goal, I could just leave them out of the circuit entirely.